# Symfony - I can not customize my form with twig

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, twig

I would like to create a login form in twig (login + password) and which is customized. The form should search the Users table and the LDAP directory if the information entered exists.

Moreover, when I validate the form, I do not want the login and the password to be found in the URL.

At validation, if the user exists, he is redirected to a page, otherwise he will remain on the login page.

I managed to make a form, customized but that returns the login and password in the URL.

It looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meJs7.png)

And this is the code in twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>rel="stylesheet"> 

{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<form class="navbar-form navbar-center">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" name="login" value="" placeholder="Login">                                        
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" placeholder="Mot de passe">                                        
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
<br/><br/>
    Pas de compte académique ? <a href="{{path('paquets_index')}}">Demande de création de compte</a>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Now my goal is to make sure that there is no login and password that are found in the URL to validation. It will just be a check and in function, it will show yes or no the next page. And I can not do it.

Moreover, from a functional point of view, is it useful to go through a formType builder from my Users entity? Or can I just be content with this kind of form, which would send back to the controller the information entered, to do the verification?

When in doubt, here is my form builder

```
<?php

namespace Site\PagesBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class ConnexionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('identifiant', TextType::class)
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class,array(
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder'=> 'Mot de passe',
                'label' =>'Mot de passe',
            )
        ))
        ;
    }/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Site\PagesBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'site_pagesbundle_user';
    }


}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, how bend on reinventing the wheel you are. But symfony has a lot of stuff prepared, since this is not that uncommon of a use case.

I like the 3.4 tutorial on building a login: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/form_login_setup.html

(at the side, there is the possibility to switch to 4.3 or whatever, however, the 3.4 tutorial should still work, even in 4.x)

you don't particularly need your own FormType to do the login, since the Security components already handle form submissions. Also have a look at csrf protection ;o)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I just read the article. So will it look in the Users table if the data entered exists, and redirect automatically?
However, it is not mentioned if this utility allows to check both a Users table and an LDAP directory, is this the case?

Comment: you have to add a new UserProvider I suspect.

Comment: @AgarioFR https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/ldap.html should do the trick, with chain user provider to first check ldap, then db

Comment: Thanks ! So this will check for LDAP, but does that mean I have to make a login form for LDAP and one for DB Users? Or can I combine both?

Comment: @AgarioFR I believe you can combine it, I'm quite certain though, that a google search will help you find out (you're not gonna be the first with that challenge ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not using your form generated by ConnexionType if you want to use it in your Twig file you can display it like that `{{form(form) }}` if you send it through your controller.

[You have all the necessary information here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html)

Then to not pass the login and password in the url use the POST method

Otherwise I recommend the security bundle [Bundle Security](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) to get a secure form

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Hello, yes my goal is precisely to use the formType while keeping exactly the same rendering (design) than the one I posted in my first photo post.

Because using the formType, I can not get the Bootstrap 3 rendering with the glyphicons correctly inserted.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/bootstrap4.html 

A first answer here to customize your form

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I finally managed to edit the form :)